# Finding indexes that aren't used often or at all

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is there a facility or a recommended practice for determining which indexes are being used and which ones can be "purged"? At the minimum, I'm looking for a log file that over time can be analyzed for which indexes were utilized. From there I can begin researching indexes that were never hit for possible candidates for a clean up.

I'm specifically not interested in running "explain" across our space of queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable the [`user_statistics`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/user-statistics/) plugin. After having this active for a while, check out the `INDEX_STATISTICS` table in the `information_schema`. The table shows which indexes have been used since last time MariaDB was started, so if they're not listed here then they're good candidates for being purged.

Also use [`pt-duplicate-key-checker`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-duplicate-key-checker.html) to find duplicated indexes.

All this is nicely written up by Federico Razzoli in [Dropping useless MySQL indexes](https://federico-razzoli.com/dropping-useless-mysql-indexes).

Answer (score 1):

(The other answer is good, but...)

If you find an index that has "never" been used, be cautious about `DROPping` it.  It may be needed in some rare admin situation.  Example:  purging "old" data.

Meanwhile, here are some examples of indexes that should be removed:

```
INDEX(a),   -- remove this, since the next handles it
INDEX(a,b)
```

but keep both of these (due to "uniqueness" constraint")

```
UNIQUE(a), INDEX(a,b)
```

A `PRIMARY KEY` *is* a key:

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),
INDEX(id)    -- remove this
```

If you are using "prefixing", the index is either not used at all, or is not reaching beyond the prefix.  Examples:

```
INDEX(foo(10))  -- Almost always better to say INDEX(foo)
```

If you have no "composite" indexes (that is, indexes with multiple columns), then you are probably in need of some.

If your goal is to save disk space, then check the datatypes.  Some people (and many 3rd-party products) blindly use `BIGINT`.  That takes 8 bytes, whereas `INT` takes only 4.  That's 8 bytes per row of the table and 8 bytes per row in each index that it occurs in.

Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for one of your tables; I may have more suggestions.

Comment: Good answer. Maybe you can elaborate on why `bar` isn't used in `INDEX(foo(10), bar)`?

Comment: @dbdemon - Thanks.  I stand corrected.  I feel that the optimizations in this area are rather complex.  I don't have a good feel for that advice to give.

Comment: @dbdemon - And I updated http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql after experimenting.